# incompatible types: EditText cannot be converted to String

Tags: android, android-edittext, firebase-authentication

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Username, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    counter--;
                    Attempt.setText("No of attempts remaining : " +counter);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (counter==0)
                        Login.setEnabled(false);
```

I put this code, but still getting the same error

```
Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validate(Username.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

At first its working, but since i replace createUserWithEmail.... with signInWithEmail... i got this error

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Username.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString())
```

You can't pass editText as parameters, since Username and password are EditTexts extract value from these and send.